# Loaded Induction Hypothesis

Tags: induction

Could anyone please explain me what is **Loaded Induction Hypothesis** and its difference from a standard one? I imagine that it must be a stronger hypothesis in some way.

Comment: I haven't heard about a "loaded induction hypothesis". Do you have a definition, or some more context?

Comment: No, this is the problem. I found an example here goo.gl/GPxER6, and don't quite get it.

Comment: Yes: he says: "then $\psi, \text {M-INT}_G(\psi) \in \Delta$. (Note that this is stronger than what is actaully needed..." Because the result needed is $\psi \in \Delta$.

Comment: So, does it mean that in this case we use a stronger assumption as IH than the one we want to prove?

Comment: (continuing the quote) "...such a **loaded induction hypothesis** makes the proof easier."

Comment: That happens some times. The typical example is that proving $\frac11+\frac14+\frac19+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}<2$ will require an induction hypothesis which is stronger, like ${}<2-\frac1n$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this term. But sometimes instead of trying to show that $P(n)\implies P(n+1),$ for every $n\in \mathbb N,$  we show that $[\;\forall m \in \mathbb N\; (m<n\implies   P(m)\;]\implies P(n).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's usually called "strong induction" (if I read your expression right). But yes, I thought about that too.